# Creating zero values in a matrix without following typical Gauss - Jordan steps.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I was presented with the following Matrix in an assignment and asked to find the value for B that would  make the rank of the matrix 2.

\begin{pmatrix}3&-3&0\\ 3&-1&2\\ b&0&2\end{pmatrix}

I solved this by using row operations to make the last row all zeros using the following steps.

Step 1: Row 2 = Row 2 - row 1.
\begin{pmatrix}3&-3&0\\ 0&2&2\\ b&0&2\end{pmatrix}

Step 2: Row 3 = Row 3 - Row2.

\begin{pmatrix}3&-3&0\\ 0&2&2\\ b&-2&0\end{pmatrix}

Step 3: Row 3 = Row 3 - 2/3*row1.

\begin{pmatrix}3&-3&0\\ 0&2&2\\ b-2&0&0\end{pmatrix}

From this b must be 2 to make the rank of the matrix 2, no? I was told this was wrong as I had used Gauss-Jordan elimination incorrectly. The answer to the question is two but I was awarded no marks for it. Why is this so wrong? Thank you!

Comment: if possible, talk to who marked you answer, they might be able to help as well

Comment: You reduced the matrix to a form in which it's easy to see that rank is two if and only if $b=2$. But if you didn't write anything to say *why* it's easy to see that, then the marker doesn't know whether you really know what you're doing, or whether you just made a lucky guess. It's rough, but that's how some folks mark.

Answer (score 1):

Your steps to arrive at the conclusion that the rank is at least $2$ are correct. But you fail to show that the rank is $2$ *if and only if* $b=2$.

You're only showing that *if* $b=2$ then the rank is $2$.

Well, you were not far from finishing correctly the argument, but as it stands it's incomplete: the form you get is not triangular. Some row swaps would suffice.

Where's the *real* problem? You took advantage from the *particular* matrix, but, as I use to say, you should think to the given matrix as a $1000\times1000$ matrix, maybe with several parameters: you don't want to start looking for promising simplifications, because it would take longer than directly performing Gauss-Jordan.

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -3 & 0 \\
3 & -1 & 2 \\
b &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
3 & -1 & 2 \\
b &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_1\gets \tfrac{1}{3}R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  2 & 2 \\
0 &  b & 2
\end{pmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned} R_2 &\gets R_2-3R_1 \\ R_3 &\gets R_3-bR_1 \end{aligned}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  1 & 1 \\
0 &  b & 2
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_2 \gets \tfrac{1}{2}R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  1 & 1 \\
0 &  0 & 2-b
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_3 \gets R_3-bR_2
\end{align}
At this point you have two possibilities: if $b=2$, the elimination stops and the rank is $2$; if $b\ne2$, you have another step and the rank is $3$.